# Send email using nodemailer angular 6

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, nodemailer

I have a `bootstrap` form for email services for `angular 6` app and `nodejs`, I am using `nodemailer` for sendemail in my app, unfortunately does not work. I am getting the following error when I submit the form:

`OPTIONS https://localhost:3000/contact/send 0 ()`

here is the form

```
 <form [formGroup]="angForm" novalidate>
    <div class="message">
      <h3> Write to us </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="form__top">
      <div class="form__left">
        <div class="form__group">
          <input class="form__input form__input--name" type="text"   formControlName="name" placeholder="name" #name>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['name'].invalid && (angForm.controls['name'].dirty || angForm.controls['name'].touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
          <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['name'].errors.required">
            Name is required.
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form__group">
          <input class="form__input form__input--email" type="email"  formControlName="email" placeholder="email" #email>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['email'].invalid && (angForm.controls['message'].dirty || angForm.controls['message'].touched)"
          class="alert alert-danger">
          <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['message'].errors.required">
            message is required.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form__right">
        <div class="form__group">
          <textarea class="form__input form__input--textarea" placeholder="Message" formControlName="message"  #message
            rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['message'].invalid && (angForm.controls['message'].dirty || angForm.controls['message'].touched)"
          class="alert alert-danger">
          <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['message'].errors.required">
            message is required.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <flash-messages></flash-messages>
    <div class="form__down">
      <div class="form__group">
        <button (click)="sendMail(name.value, email.value, message.value)" [disabled]="angForm.pristine || angForm.invalid"  class="form__input form__input--submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="SEND MESSAGE">SEND MESSAGE
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </form>
```

Here is contact,js (node mailer settings and routes)

```
  const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const request = require('request');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const cors = require('cors');

router.options('/send', cors()); 
router.get('/send', cors(), (req, res) => {
    const outputData = `
    <p>You have a new contact request</p>
    <h3>Contact Details</h3>
    <ul>  
      <li>Name: ${req.body.name}</li>
      <li>Email: ${req.body.email}</li>
    </ul>
    <h3>Message</h3>
    <p>${req.body.message}</p>
  `;

    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        port: 465,
        secure: false,
        port: 25,
        auth: {
            user: 'email',
            pass: 'pass'
        },
        tls: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
    });

    let HelperOptions = {
        from: '"kutomba" <email',
        to: 'email',
        subject: 'Majeni Contact Request',
        text: 'Hello',
        html: outputData
    };



    transporter.sendMail(HelperOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
        console.log("The message was sent!");
        console.log(info);
    });

});
module.exports = router;
```

here is the server js.
**UPDATE**

```
// server.js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
// CORS Middleware
app.use(cors());
// Port Number
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
// Run the app by serving the static files
// in the dist directory
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/majeni/dist/majeni')));
// Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
//routes
const contact = require('./app/routes/contact');
app.use('/contact', contact);
// If an incoming request uses
// a protocol other than HTTPS,
// redirect that request to the
// same url but with HTTPS
const forceSSL = function () {
  return function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] !== 'https') {
      return res.redirect(
        ['https://', req.get('Host'), req.url].join('')
      );
    }
    next();
  }
}

// Instruct the app
// to use the forceSSL
// middleware
app.use(forceSSL());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

  // Website you wish to allow to connect
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');

  // Request methods you wish to allow
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

  // Request headers you wish to allow
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

  // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
  // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

  // Pass to next layer of middleware
  if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
    res.sendStatus(200);
    } else {
      next();
    }

});

// For all GET requests, send back index.html
// so that PathLocationStrategy can be used
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/majeni/dist/majeni/index.html'));
});

// Start Server
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server started on port '+port);
  });
```

**UPDATE**

Here is service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Jsonp } from '@angular/http';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ContactService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  sendEmail(name, email, message) {
    const uri = 'http://localhost:3000/contact/send';
    const obj = {
      name: name,
      email: email,
      message: message,
    };
    return this.http.post(uri, obj);
  }
}
```

**UPDATE : component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ContactService } from '../../contact.service';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { FlashMessagesModule, FlashMessagesService } from 'angular2-flash-messages';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-footer',
  templateUrl: './footer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./footer.component.scss']
})
export class FooterComponent implements OnInit {
  angForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(
    private flashMessages: FlashMessagesService,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private contactService: ContactService) {
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm() {
    this.angForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['', Validators.required],
      message: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }
  sendMail(name, email, message) {
    this.contactService.sendEmail(name, email, message).subscribe(success => {
      this.flashMessages.show('You are data we succesfully submitted', { cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 3000 });
      console.log(success);
    }, error => {
      this.flashMessages.show('Something went wrong', { cssClass: 'alert-danger', timeout: 3000 });
    });
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

What is  missing in my code?

Comment: seems to be cors issue, enable in nodejs side

Comment: I have enabled now cors in my server.js still the same :(   I have updated the server,js in my thread check it :)

Comment: @hamilton.lima I have updated the code :)

Comment: @user9964622: I am trying to achieve exactly this! Is there a way you could share the code? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your forceSSL function is redirecting your http call to an non existing https endpoint.

All the code looks fine btw

Comment out this line in server.js

```
// app.use(forceSSL());
```

Edit

Also change the endpoint in your service to match what you have in the server, it should be /contact only

```
app.use('/contact', contact);
```

Comment: Updated the response ;) have fun